# How to fix foreign key errors in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I am creating a database using Ubuntu and I am trying to add a foreign key to the below table. Here's my code.

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicles (    
    Vehicle_ID int NOT NULL,
    Vehicle_Type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Model_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Engine_Size numeric(2,1) NOT NULL,
    Vehicle_Condition VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Price numeric(9,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Vehicle_ID)
);


CREATE TABLE Models (
    Model_ID int NOT NULL,
    Manufacturer VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Model_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Wheel_Drive_Type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Model_ID)
);
```

Whenever I run the below code it returns an error "ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint" and I have no idea why - especially as they both have the same input type.

```
ALTER TABLE Vehicles
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Model_Name) REFERENCES Models(Model_Name);
```

> ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Well, the primary key is `Model_ID` so that seems much more suitable for the foreign key reference.

Answer (score 1):

As per https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

The FK you need want to create must refer to the Models table PK which is Model_ID.

You are trying to link it to Model_name  which is not unique.

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicles (    
Vehicle_ID int NOT NULL,
Vehicle_Type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Model_ID INT NOT NULL,
Engine_Size numeric(2,1) NOT NULL,
Vehicle_Condition VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Price numeric(9,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Vehicle_ID)
);


CREATE TABLE Models (
    Model_ID int NOT NULL,
    Manufacturer VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Model_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Wheel_Drive_Type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Model_ID)
);
```

And you will be allowed to do

```
ALTER TABLE Vehicles
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Model_ID ) REFERENCES Models(Model_ID );
```

As proved here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b6ad7

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by doing a few things. Everything that I did to correct this came from here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html

Specifically the header: "Foreign Keys and Other Constraints"

There were a couple things I noticed and changed. The first that caught my eye is that you're using Model_name as a foreign key, even though it's not a primary key on the models table. I'm not sure that this is a requirement, but it seemed off.

Opinion: foreign and primary key fields should always be "IDs" and not "Names". Therefore, I replaced the model_name field in Vehicles with Model ID, and updated to INT (to match Models).

Then I changed the syntax slightly in alter table:

```
ALTER TABLE Vehicles
    ADD CONSTRAINT model_FK FOREIGN KEY (Model_ID) REFERENCES Models(Model_ID);
```

This all worked!

I think if you wanted to use Model_name as a foreign key in Vehicles, it either needs to be made the primary key of Models, or you can add an index on Models with Model_name. That is more in line with the error message I was seeing when I tried to alter the table to create the model_name FK... something about a "missing index for constraint in referenced table Models".

Answer (score -1):

It may be because you're trying to use a Varchar field as a foreign key and MySQL doesn't like to use VarChar for keys unless they are specified as BINARY. It's also fussy about specifying CHARSET and COLLATE properties as well/

Adding BINARY to the column spec and ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci; to the table specs should solve it. EG:

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicles (    
    Vehicle_ID int NOT NULL,
    Vehicle_Type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Model_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Engine_Size numeric(2,1) NOT NULL,
    Vehicle_Condition VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Price numeric(9,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Vehicle_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE Models (
    Model_ID int NOT NULL,
    Manufacturer VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Model_name VARCHAR(255) BINARY NOT NULL,
    Wheel_Drive_Type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Model_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: I believe in explaining downvotes, so here's why I downvoted: MySQL does not require BINARY for foreign keys, it only requires that the FK column has the same collation as the PK column it references. Your answer also totally misses the real problem, which is that the FK in the OP's question is referencing a non-key column.